# How to add sample number to stacked barchart and check significance in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, bar-chart

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like below:

```
df <- structure(list(Samples = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", 
"sample5", "sample6", "sample7", "sample8", "sample9", "sample10", 
"sample11", "sample12", "sample13", "sample14", "sample15", "sample16", 
"sample17", "sample18", "sample19", "sample20", "sample21", "sample22", 
"sample23", "sample24", "sample25", "sample26", "sample27", "sample28", 
"sample29", "sample30", "sample31", "sample32", "sample33", "sample34", 
"sample35", "sample36", "sample37", "sample38", "sample39", "sample40", 
"sample41", "sample42"), new = c("Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", 
"Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", 
"Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", 
"Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", 
"Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus1", "Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", 
"Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2", 
"Clus2", "Clus2", "Clus2"), Groups = c("GroupB", "GroupF", "GroupC", 
"GroupD", "GroupF", "GroupD", "GroupA", "GroupC", "GroupE", "GroupD", 
"GroupB", "GroupE", "GroupF", "GroupC", "GroupC", "GroupC", "GroupA", 
"GroupA", "GroupA", "GroupE", "GroupC", "GroupB", "GroupC", "GroupC", 
"GroupF", "GroupB", "GroupF", "GroupF", "GroupE", "GroupA", "GroupD", 
"GroupE", "GroupF", "GroupB", "GroupD", "GroupD", "GroupE", "GroupE", 
"GroupD", "GroupD", "GroupE", "GroupD")), row.names = c(NA, -42L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using the above data I made a stacked barchart plot:

```
group.colors <- c("GroupA"="skyblue","GroupB"="brown", "GroupC"="purple", "GroupD"="darkblue",
                  "GroupE"="darkgreen", "GroupF"="#FF8D00")
ggplot(df,aes(x = new,fill = Groups)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=group.colors)
```

And the Figure looks like below:

[image]

1. How to add the sample number on the figure for each Group in the Clus1 and Clus2?
2. GroupE and GroupF are both seen in Clus1 and Clsu2. So, how to check their asssociation? Any example of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the sample number like this:

```r
ggplot(df,aes(x = new,fill = Groups)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..), color = "white", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=group.colors)
```

[image]

The second question isn't really clear, but you can check whether the proportion of E and F are significantly different between the two clusters using a Fisher's exact test - perhaps that's what you mean?

```r
fisher.test(with(df[df$Groups %in% c("GroupE", "GroupF"),], table(Groups, new)))
#> 
#>  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
#> 
#> data:  with(df[df$Groups %in% c("GroupE", "GroupF"), ], table(Groups, new))
#> p-value = 0.1189
#> alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.001827082 1.768053629
#> sample estimates:
#> odds ratio 
#>  0.1189474
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My second question is - I would like to check the enrichment of GroupE is with Clus1 or Clus2 with significance test? I want to do it individually for GroupE and GroupF

Comment: @beginner I don't understand what you mean. What is enrichment? Do you mean you wish to compare the relative frequency of each group between the two clusters? The Fisher test _is_ the correct significance test for small counts like these.

Comment: What I mean is I want to know whether GroupE is associated with Clus1 or Clus2? Yes, `fisher.test` is the best for that. I want to get p-value individually with GroupE and GroupF.

Comment: when I do the `fisher.test` separately for GroupE and GroupF, it givess an Error: 'x' must have at least 2 rows and columns

Comment: @beginner but that's because in that case you are just comparing two numbers - like in Group F you are asking "is 1 significantly different from 6?" That doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps you want to test the proportions of "Group E" within each cluster against each other - that would make sense and could be done with a Fisher test

Comment: So, in the `fisher.test` what if I want to check the association of only one group with Clus1 or Clus2? How this can be done?